# "npm install express" ERROR missing package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

During my installation of express I'm receiving these warnings.

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\node\demo\package.json'
npm WARN demo No description
npm WARN demo No repository field.
npm WARN demo No README data
npm WARN demo No license field.
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: You create a [package.json file](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) for your project. Or you can just ignore it, since it's just a warning, not an error.

Comment: how can I create package.json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type "npm init" to interactively create a package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

The warning you see is due to the `--save` flag you added to the command.  If you are not creating a npm package, remove the `--save` from the command.  If you are creating a npm package, run `npm init` from your projects root directory, then run the install again.

Comment: i didn't add --save